# I have a an address field in the data frame which looks like this

Tags: python, pandas

My Address column of the dataframe looks like this.

874 E 139th St Mott Haven, BX

455 E 148th St South Bronx, BX

3952 3rd Ave Tremont, BX

**I want this column to look like this.**

St Mott Haven

St South Bronx

Ave Tremont

how can I do that using pandas.

Comment: Ave or St exists always?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex pattern:

```
df['address'] = df['address'].str.extract(r'\b(\D+)\b,')
```

#### Explanation

- `\b` word boundary
- `(\D+)\b,` capture group - any characters, including whitespace that does **not** contain a number, upto but not including a comma.